# If multiple Django apps define the same custom management command, which is used?

Tags: python, django, manage.py

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/) are silent on this questios. Will the commands be registered in order, with later apps (in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` order) overriding previous commands (whether custom from other apps or the built-in Django commands)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, as of the current 1.7 release.

See [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L75) in the Django source to see where the logic is implemented: in the order of apps per the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` tuple, each app's management commands are added to a dictionary of commands (which was initialized with Django's built-in commands [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L68)), with a single slot for any given command name, so that last one added sticks, overriding any previous app's (or Django's built-in) command with the same name; when executing a command (code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L80)), Django uses the dictionary above to decide which command logic to actually use.

Note I haven't found any documentation of this, so it should technically be considered unofficial behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Commands are registered in **reverse** app order (see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/core/management/__init__.py#L73)). So to override `FooCommand` in app `foo` with your own version in app `bar`, `bar` must *precede* `foo` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

This is unfortunate, because you may need `bar` to follow `foo` for other reasons. E.g., if `bar`'s models reference `foo`'s models.

One solution is to split the overriding command out into a separate app, if feasible.

Answer (score 1):

From [Django 2.2 official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps)

> When several applications provide different versions of the same resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the application listed first in INSTALLED_APPS has precedence.